# iOS: Change color of my UIButton if the background image have same color of the button

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uibutton

I have a `UIImageView` that gets an image from the server, above it on the top right I have a `UIButton` of white color that I made. Now If the image in the `imageview` was white near my button, my `button` wont appear well since the background and my `button` are white. I want a way to be able to change the button background `color`, if the image `color` is same of the `button` background `color`.

Comment: Show your coding till now what you tried

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
-(void) getPixelColorAtLocation:(CGPoint)point
{
    unsigned char pixel[4] = {0};
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(pixel, 1, 1, 8, 4, colorSpace, kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);

    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -point.x, -point.y);

    [self.layer renderInContext:context];

    CGContextRelease(context);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    NSLog(@"RGB Color code %d  %d  %d",pixel[0],pixel[1],pixel[2]);
}
```

It will help you to find the background color.